# Hide Nivo slider caption for mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. At the moment I have a Nivo Slider, with a Nivo Caption set to display: none; at a certain screen size. It has come to me attention that for some people, seems like iPhones, the caption displays, and creates a white space to the right (too big for the current size), until refreshed. Is there a better way to 'get rid' of an element for mobile?

Thanks.
Al.

Comment: I'm not sure if looking at the code will achieve a whole lot. I can give you a link to the site - [link](http://www.clickstream.ie/index.php) - the display: none; does what it's supposed to, but apparently on an iPhone it's still visible (sometimes) until the page is refreshed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting a CSS rule.

At some point on the Stylesheet you have:

```
.theme-light .nivo-caption {
    display: none;
}
```

A bit further:

```
.nivo-caption {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    bottom: 10%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 66px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 440px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

display: none;

and then

display: block;

I would go for a jQuery approach to get rid of the caption, based on the screen size or even detecting if it's a smartphone (modernizr).

Comment: Thanks for that. I have 3 style sheets and where that CSS code is, is the last style sheet in the HTML. At the bottom of that I have a media query with

'.nivo-caption {
    display: none;
 }'
so I thought that should cover it. I've removed 'display: block' and it seems to still work fine on a desktop, you think that might solve the issue? I will look at a jQuery approach now (thought that might be best, but might need some more help on that)

Comment: I'm not sure how compatible is the media query with smartphone browsers, so if you go through modernizr detection + some simple jQuery, for sure it will work.

Comment: Glad I could help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

in the jquery.nivo.slider.js

add:

```
//Process  caption
        if ($(window).width() < 659) {
            $('.nivo-caption').hide();
        }
        else {
            processCaption(settings);
        }
```